# How to use an array as a parameter?

Tags: arrays, powershell, prompt

I want to prompt for options from a programmatically generated list.

Background:
I have 2 AWS accounts with containing different environments.
The script automatically detects which account you are in, and then it should prompt for which environment you want to join.

I'm trying this:

```
$envs = "
1,Dev
1,Test
1,Demo
2,Staging
2,Production
" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","  -header "awsAccount","Environment"

$awsAccount = Determine-awsAccount

$envs = ([string]($allServers.Environment | Where-Object -property awsAccount -eq $awsAccount | Sort-Object |  Get-unique)).replace(" ",",")

$title = "Deploy into which environment"
$message = "Please select which environment you want to deploy into"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($envs)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
```

You can create a pop-up of options using
`$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]("yes","no")`

But in my case it's popping up one option containing all my environments, separated by commas. I want it to pop up one option for each (relevant) environment.

How can I pop the string list of environments back out from the in-PowerShell world to the outside-PowerShell world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading your question as:

> When awsAccount 1 is relevant, give the options for awsAccount 1 (Dev,
> test, Demo)"
>
> When awsAccount 2 is relevant, give the options for awsAccount 2 (Demo,
> Staging, Production)"

Main change is to your `$envs = ([string](..` line. I've used a new variable `$envsToDisplayInPrompt` to avoid confusion with original `$envs`.

**Code:**

```
$envs = "
1,Dev
1,Test
1,Demo
2,Staging
2,Production
" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","  -header "awsAccount","Environment"

#$awsAccount = Determine-awsAccount
$awsAccount = 1   # assuming Determine-awsAccount returns an integer 1 or 2

#$envs = ([string]($allServers.Environment | Where-Object -property awsAccount -eq $awsAccount | Sort-Object |  Get-unique)).replace(" ",",")
$envsToDisplayInPrompt = @(($envs | Where-Object {$_.awsAccount -eq $awsAccount}).Environment)

$title = "Deploy into which environment"
$message = "Please select which environment you want to deploy into"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($envsToDisplayInPrompt)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
```

**Output:**

[image: Prompt output]

Comment: That's awesome. So is the main change that you have used a different kind of variables? I can see it works, but can't see how.

Comment: I changed the condition to $_.awsAccount -like "*"+$awsAccount+"*" to get it to work.

Comment: @RichardMoore Glad to here it's working. The main change is to the line `$envs = ([string](..` as I'm not convinced this is correctly returning the string array required by `$options =...`. You can test this using `Write-Host $env` _after_ this line and seeing what it prints. Using the same variable name is normally fine; I'm using different one for clarity.